# installing .deb file without internet connection without software centre

Tags: installation, live-usb, deb

i want to install OS uninstaller i have its .deb file and the two other dependency files(.deb) required for it but when i try to install the dependency file in the liveUSB the software center opens and the install button is grayed out, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Try  this :

Install `GDebi` by running the following command on the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

After it is installed go to your .deb file, right-click and 'open with GDebi'.

or

```
cd /path/to/the/directoy/which/contains/.deb/file
sudo gdebi filename.deb
```

It will install the package along with it's dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Avinish Raj. I will try to emulate that style in future.

Comment: Will he be able to apt-get gdebi without an internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via command line:

```
cd /path-to-directory-that-contains-the-deb-files
sudo dpkg -i XXX.deb
```